# SNMP Walk without specifying oid in Polycom device

Tags: snmp, mib, snmp4j, oid

I would like to do an snmp walk on a Polycom device.But I don't know the oid of the root node from where the walk must be started.By walking without specifying an oid i am getting no result.How can I get the oid of the root node for starting the snmp walk.

The root oid for the Polycom device is .1.3.6.1.4.1.2684. Is there any way to dynamically identify the root oid of an snmp device, so that we can start walk from that oid

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `.1.3` as starting point. This is the root element of 99.9% MIB files.

Comment: I already tried .1.3 .But it's not working for Polycom device

Comment: It should work just fine because Polycom private tree starts at `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2684`. If it does not work you should contact the hardware vendor and report the bug in SNMP agent implementation.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin, unfortunatly buggy SNMP implementations are very common. I have encountered in my practice with devices which uses oids like `0.3.6.1` for `system`.

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin, The root oid for the Polycom device is .1.3.6.1.4.1.2684. Is there any way to dynamically identify the root oid of an snmp device, so that we can start walk from that oid

Comment: @AndrewKomiagin, I can perform snmp walk if I give the starting oid as .1.3.6.1.4.1.2684.But when I give the starting oid as .1.3 for performing snmp walk I am getting a response "No Data Available".My requirement is I need to dynamically get the starting oid of an snmp device for performing snmp walk

Comment: Have you tried .1.3.6.1.4.1 as starting point? As for Polycom SNMP Agent it is definitely buggy. To workaround this you could try .1.3 first then if no data .1.3.6.1.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.` or `0.0` as starting point, at least if you using `snmpwalk` command from `net-snmp` utils. Also you can use `sysObjectID` (`1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2`) to get system oid for specific device, but only if your device supports `system` branch.

Comment: I have try this.I can only start snmp walk for polycom device with starting oid .1.3.6.1.4.1.2684 and using sysobjectid.My requirement is I need to dynamically identify the starting oid of an snmp device to perform snmp walk.